# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library php_pdo_firebird

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to upload a 35Mb XML file.

But i got this error in the error_log from php

> [22-Feb-2018 10:03:12 Europe/Belgrade] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup:
>   Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\PHP\v5.6\ext\php_pdo_firebird.dll' - The specified module could
>   not be found.

How can i debug this??

Comment: What is the output of this in `cmd`? `if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.6\ext\php_pdo_firebird.dll" ( echo FILE EXISTS ) else ( echo THE FILE DOES NOT EXIST LOL )`

Comment: Yes, it exists!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the 32 bits zip package from the firebird site. in the bin dir there is a fbclient.dll. Copy this dll to the php dir. (Not to the extension dir) and everything works.

[Answer Reference](https://forums.iis.net/t/1220633.aspx?PHP%20Startup%20Unable%20to%20load%20dynamic%20library%20php_pdo_firebird%20dll)

Author Name: ronaldk

Comment: it does not work from the php bin dir.. ONLY FROM APACHE BIN !!!

Answer (score 4):

The `php_pdo_firebird.dll` is only an interface between PHP and the firebird engine. So you need firebird installed and also the `php-pdo-firebird.dll` needs to be able to find `fbclient.dll`

Try copying `fbclient.dll` into `\wamp\bin\php\php7.1.10`

If you also need access from Apache you may need to copy `fbclient.dll` into `\wamp\bin\apache\apache{version}\bin` as well and also amend the `php.ini` file that controls PHP under apache. Do that by using the wampmanager menus to edit the correct `php.ini` file like this

> left click wampmanager icon -> PHP -> php.ini

Answer (score 4):

For me, it got fixed after copying fbclient.dll file into the php installation folder. You have to download the Zip kit for manual/custom installs from the firebird [website](https://firebirdsql.org/en/firebird-3-0/#Win64). You can find the file there. 64 bit version worked.

Answer (score 1):

copying fbclient to php bin did not work for me (and I spent a whole day trying to copy different versions of it).. instead copy it to apache/bin folder and it works (for me it was 64x version that worked)

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is simply comment it out if you don't need it

; PHP_PDO_FIREBIRD

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).